# Unable to find a way to pass data to CKEditor 5 plugin

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am developing a plugin which when the user presses enter from a given cursor position, it copies the content from the right side of the cursor and afterwards deletes it.

The problem that I currently have is that I cannot find a way that I can pass data to my plugin when I am initiating the editor in my core application.

This is the plugin code that I am experimenting with:

```
export default class CopyOnEnter extends Plugin {
  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    editor.editing.view.document.on("keydown", (evt, data) => {
      if (data.keyCode === 13 && passedDataToPlugin === "something") {
        const pos = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
        const posEnd = Position._createAt(pos.root, "end");

        const rangeAfter = new Range(pos, posEnd);
        const fragAfter = editor.model.getSelectedContent(
          new Selection([rangeAfter])
        );
        const dataAfterEnterKey = editor.data.stringify(fragAfter);
        editor.model.deleteContent(new Selection([rangeAfter]));

        console.log("dataAfterEnterKey", dataAfterEnterKey);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I am currently investigating the use of commands, but I am still unable to wrap my head around those.

Worst case scenario I will use localstorage to pass the data, which is not an optimal solution for the given problem IMO.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! What is the use case for that plugin? Don't get me wrong, it just sounds weird because <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the essential key for any text editor and using it for that purpose just feels odd. It would be great to know more before giving you any concrete advice.

Comment: Hi @oleq, first I want to thank you for showing interest in my question.
The use case is the following, I am creating a small angular app which provides user interface for quick article creation, and I was given the task of implementing the following functionality: When the user is writing a paragraph and presses enter in the middle of the text for example a new row will be created with the content from the right side of the cursor. Because I am defining the rows as different types (paragraph, heading, quote...) I need to pass the row type to the plugin, which leads to my main question.

Comment: Additionally I am only overriding the <kbd>Enter</kbd> only for rows of type paragraph.